# Move mesh manually or rig character?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

blender beginner here. I have managed to draw a low poly human character mesh in a symmetrical standing pose. I would like to put the human into an asymmetrical yoga pose, but struggled to draw this from scratch. What would be the best/easiest way to manipulate the standing mesh into the yoga pose? Should I rig the mesh or can move the mesh manually?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Yes the best is probably to rig it to an armature

Comment: You may also want to have a look at this 
https://youtu.be/YN9iSNO9KKc?feature=shared